# How to select child nodes but the first element

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

So I got a table and I want to set a style in all `<tr>` elements but the first. Example:

```html
<table>
    <tr><th>This receives header styles</th></tr>
    <tr><td>This receives item styles</td></tr>
    <tr><td>This receives item styles</td></tr>
    <tr><td>This receives item styles</td></tr>
</table>
```

I know I have to use selectors but I don't know how and can't find it on the web =S

Comment: [Selectors from w3c with CSS versions](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#selectors)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The general sibling selector `~` lets you select every certain element that comes after another. You can use this selector:

```
table tr:first-child ~ tr
```

Works in IE7+.

If you can modify your HTML to make it more semantic, you can place your first row with the `th` cells in a `thead`, and the rest in a `tbody`:

```html
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr><th>This receives header styles</th></tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr><td>This receives item styles</td></tr>
    <tr><td>This receives item styles</td></tr>
    <tr><td>This receives item styles</td></tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Then use this selector instead:

```
table tbody tr
```

Works on older browsers in case you need it.

Comment: +1, especially for the second option, which is better semantically.

Comment: I'll stay with second option. I've been using 3 tables, one for header, body and other for footer. But I'll change for just one like you said. Thank a lot !

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#table-id tr').not(':first-child').addClass('class');
```

should do it

Comment: Thank you, but I have to do it without jquery.